# Touchpad won't work after installing Ubuntu 18

Tags: 18.04, touchpad, synaptics, input

I recently wiped my M.2 drive to switch from Windows to Ubuntu 18.04.2 and my touchpad does not work at all. This includes the right and left mouse buttons. I am using an ASUS G752 gaming laptop. I have GNOME 3.28.2 and have switched to using nvidia drivers already to support my graphics card (touchpad did not work before or after switch). If I go into terminal and input `xinput -list` it outputs

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Asus Keyboard                             id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Asus Keyboard                             id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN1203:00 04F3:301E Touchpad            id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=18   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=19   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech K400 Plus                        id=21   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus Wireless Radio Control               id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam: USB2.0 HD           id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus Keyboard                             id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus Keyboard                             id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=20   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech K400 Plus                        id=22   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I think the ELAN1203:00 04F3:301E Touchpad is the touchpad I want to use however I cannot seem to get it to work. When I enter `xinput list-props` 14` I get

```
Device 'ELAN1203:00 04F3:301E Touchpad':
    Device Enabled (152):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (154): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (282): 1
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (283):   2.500000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (284):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (285):    25.000000
    Synaptics Edges (302):  139, 3359, 103, 1805
    Synaptics Finger (303): 25, 30, 0
    Synaptics Tap Time (304):   180
    Synaptics Tap Move (305):   175
    Synaptics Tap Durations (306):  180, 180, 100
    Synaptics ClickPad (307):   0
    Synaptics Middle Button Timeout (308):  75
    Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure (309):    282
    Synaptics Two-Finger Width (310):   7
    Synaptics Scrolling Distance (311): -79, 79
    Synaptics Edge Scrolling (312): 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling (313):   0, 0
    Synaptics Move Speed (314): 1.000000, 1.750000, 0.050201, 0.000000
    Synaptics Off (315):    0
    Synaptics Locked Drags (316):   0
    Synaptics Locked Drags Timeout (317):   5000
    Synaptics Tap Action (318): 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 2
    Synaptics Click Action (319):   1, 3, 2
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling (320): 0
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling Distance (321):    0.100000
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling Trigger (322): 0
    Synaptics Circular Pad (323):   0
    Synaptics Palm Detection (324): 0
    Synaptics Palm Dimensions (325):    10, 200
    Synaptics Coasting Speed (326): 20.000000, 50.000000
    Synaptics Pressure Motion (327):    30, 160
    Synaptics Pressure Motion Factor (328): 1.000000, 1.000000
    Synaptics Resolution Detect (329):  1
    Synaptics Grab Event Device (330):  0
    Synaptics Gestures (331):   1
    Synaptics Capabilities (332):   1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0
    Synaptics Pad Resolution (333): 31, 31
    Synaptics Area (334):   0, 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Noise Cancellation (335): 19, 19
    Device Product ID (275):    1267, 12318
    Device Node (274):  "/dev/input/event11"
```

I tried enabling it using `xinput` although I don't fully understand the usage of the command so I may have missed something. Besides that I tried a few other minor things that don't come to mind right now. I tried poking around in my bios a little bit but to no effect. I installed Synaptics and rebooted and nothing. Any idea how to get my touchpad to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below command and if it is not detecting touchpad in the output then it means Ubuntu don't support your touchpad unfortunately.

> less /proc/bus/input/devices

After that or if you have already done step 3 you can try

> sudo rmmod i2c_hid
>
> sudo modprobe i2c_hid

If it is showing your touchpad you have to edit the configuration file for GRUB.

> sudo nano /etc/default/grub

and replace

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"

with

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="i8042.reset quiet splash"

save the file and exit, then run

> sudo update-grub

and restart your laptop.

Comment: This worked for me. Many thanks!
sudo rmmod i2c_hid

sudo modprobe i2c_hid

Comment: well i'm glad it worked for you.... enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

as you are having problem with your touch pad, I want to know if you updated your system
First use **Ctrl + Alt + T** to open terminal
and than write:

> sudo apt-get update

I think after getting updates it will help....

Comment: Tried that already/tried it again and still nothing.

Comment: thank you for reply Sir.... and ok than I will come back to assist you....

Comment: sir see this website if you can.... https://itsfoss.com/fix-right-click-touchpad-ubuntu/  may be it can help you